# Foundation open reveal via Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I try to open a foundation reveal via Javascript but I always get an error, the reveal-bg is shown and the reveal itself is not visible.

```
$("#msgModal").foundation("reveal", "open");
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="#msgModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-raveal>     
   <h1>Advice</h1>      
   <a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
</div>
```

The error message in my console:

```
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'settings.css')
```

I read the documentation and also put the foundation.reveal.js under my foundation.min.js like this:

```
<script src="/layout/cyt/js/assets/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="/layout/cyt/js/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script src="/layout/cyt/js/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
```

This drives my crazy. I don't want to trigger a click or something like this. The modal should open on page load.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but are you doing the following?

Place this before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Then the following should be AFTER the above, but before the `</body>` tag.

```
$("#msgModal").foundation("reveal", "open");
```